# Paypal IPN data

Tags: php, mysql, paypal, payment, paypal-ipn

I'm adding Paypal to my website, and I also created a page to receive data from Paypal IPN. In  PHP file that I receive my paypal IPN, I add user's email that used for paypal to my database. So I was wondering what if user did not have a paypal email, and directly select to pay via his or her credit card in paypal Page. What kinda data do I receive from IPN ? Is there any email in there too ? Thanks
[image]

Comment: You can (should) try that all using the Paypal Sandbox.

Comment: Did you read this? https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/sell/ipn-test-outside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there will be an email even if the user doesn't have a PayPal account. If they choose to pay via a credit card, PayPal will ask them to enter a valid email in the payment form.

*Caveat*: If the user doesn't have a PayPal account, there is no guarantee that the email address you get will be correct. PayPal doesn't verify that the address they enter actually works. I've personally encountered a situation where the user accidentally mistyped their address and so never received the purchase confirmation/product.

(Source: I'm using PayPal IPN on one of my own sites and have tested this.)